# RabbitMQ Client- Is there a portable class library version

Tags: xamarin, rabbitmq, portable-class-library

Does anyone know if there is a portable class library (PCL) version of the RabbitMQ client libraries that could be used in the developmentof a Xamarin mobile application?

If nor does anyone know of a similar AMPQ client as a PCL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

While using Xamarin, you can communicate (send/receive push-notifications) with rabbitMQ using Rabbitmq-web-STOMP plugin activated on broker end, and use socket-io at Xamarin (using web sockets).For details regarding how to do it in xamarin [see here](https://github.com/betai/Xamarin.Socket.IO). Use the example code that gets generated after you install the stomp and stomp examples on rabbitServer by :

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp
```

`rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples`

for rabbitly-details have a look [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html), and into the source of "echo" example .

Comment: Thanks for this. But I cannot use Beta code in a production environment. What I want is a RabbitMQ or AMQP client.

Answer (score 1):

Well, RabbitMQ.Client requires .NET Standard 1.5, and Xamarin.Andorid and Xamarin.iOS provide.NET Standard 1.6:  https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md

P.S. make sure to convert your projects to package.json structure instead of "old" nuget packages.config. dotnet build tools are also a must (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3?)